# Check if assembly has been loaded

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a programmatic way to determine when an assembly itself has been loaded?

I know how to check for loaded assemblies out of the executing assembly, but I want to do it from "inside" the assembly that's going to be loaded.

This way I could determine that the application (which is using the loaded assembly) has been started, but no class from my loaded assembly has been instantiated / no method has been called thus far.

Comment: @DJKRAZE OP says they know how to do that, and are looking for a different approach.

Comment: Intuitively, this doesn't seem possible. You're asking an assembly to ask "have I been loaded?" - but to do so, the assembly needs to be loaded into a context where it can be executed.

Comment: @Michael That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Loading into a context where it can be executed will be done by my entry assembly, I assume... And now I was guessing there way maybe some event or reflection thing I could use to be notified about being loaded.

Comment: I think you would get better responces if you reworded your question from "Check if assembly has been loaded" to "Check if a class has been loaded", as from your last sentence you don't really care about the assembly, only the classes in it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But what if the assembly is loaded but no class out of it has been instantiated?

Comment: Then, the assembly is loaded and no class out of it has been instantiated. I don't understand what your question to me is.

Comment: There you go: `public static bool IsAssemblyLoaded() { return true; }`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this information you are looking for. Give us the big picture of if you had "a programmatic way to determine when an assembly itself has been loaded" what problem would you be able to solve that you are currently trying to solve. See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a function that is called when a module/assembly is loaded. In the pre-.NET world it was the DllMain function. A corresponding function exists in .NET but for whatever reason you can't create it in C# or VB.NET just in C++/CLI. It is called module constructor. You can manipulate your assembly to inject such module constructor. So whenever the assembly is loaded this function is called from inside the assembly before further access to this assembly. How to do it is explained here: http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/

Comment: +1. Note that simply loading assembly does not formally guarantee that the module constructor will run. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I really can't understand why MS introduces such a useful feature but hides the information about it and the possibility to use it.

Comment: Fratyx, what would you use it for? (possibility of random piece of code to run at almost arbitrary moment of time in security context that happen to be set at that moment never made me happy... but good place to make practical joke on next developer I guess :)...)

Comment: We check the licence key of our product. We spent many time in creating the libraries in the modules and try to prevent them being used without licence by just skipping our main application and reference them in a foreign application. (I know it is possible in spite but considerably more difficult.)